# How can I rewrite text files into up to down format? (Python 3)

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, text, format

I guess I should try and explain what I'm doing, I'm trying to get a text file to be rewritten into a separate file from left-to-right format into up-to-down format.  Here is an example:

Hello, 
this is a text file

H  t
e  h
l   i
l   s
o  
,   i
   s

  a

   t
    e
    x
    t
  
    f
    i
    l
    e

I know this example above is not perfect, but formatting this in html is a lot harder than in a text file.  Anyways, that's what I'm trying to do, however when my program gets to the for loop in the function writeToFile, this for loop:

for a_line in r_file:

For some reason it just stops and doesn't do anything after that? I'm not exactly sure why this is happening as the function maxLineLeng has the same kind of loop and it works just fine.  If you need me to explain some more stuff I can and if you can help that'd be fantastic!

BTW I am trying to do it this way in order to avoid memory usage, as just copying over each line into a list would not work if you had an extremely long line in a text file or if the text file was just gigantic.

```
# Silly downward lists for lines of text in a file
# Description:  Takes lines in a file and prints them from top to bottom
# instead of from left to right.



# What this does is it goes through a text file and goes through each character in each line.
# It then writes those characters to a separate file from left to right format to up and down format
# It does this by going through each first character of each line in read file and
# writing it to the write file.  Then it goes to the second character of each line in read file
# and writes that character to a newline in the write file.
# Keeps going until it reaches the end of the longest line in the sequence

# Finds the line with max length and returns that length.
def maxLineLeng(r_file):
    Max = 0
    for a_line in r_file:
        if len(a_line) > Max:
            Max = len(a_line)

    return Max

# Writes to the file in up to down format
def writeToFile(r_file, w_file, i):
    if i != 0:
        w_file.write("\n")
        for a_line in r_file:
            if len(a_line) > i:
                w_file.write(a_line(i))
                w_file.write(" ")
    else:
        for a_line in r_file:
            if len(a_line) > i:
                w_file.write(a_line(i))
                w_file.write(" ")

# open necessary files in proper format
def main():
    with open("exampleR.txt",'r') as r_file: # 'with' automatically closes the file
        with open("exampleW.txt",'w') as w_file:
            Max = maxLineLeng(r_file)
            for i in range(Max):
                writeToFile(r_file, w_file, i)

# begin the program
main()
input("\n\nPress enter to quit")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you go trought your file `r_file` the first time in maxLineLeng, so the 'reading cursor' of the file get at the end of your file, you have to put it again at the beginning after your first loop or before the second one

`r_file.seek(0)`

Comment: Oh man! That's right thanks! I thought it was simple but was just not seeing it for some reason! Thanks a bunch! Super stoked!

Comment: your welcome, can you just put the answer i gave you as right to close the post? ;)